# Deleting a file throws exception when is use, despite of using Polly

Tags: c#, ioexception, polly

I'm trying to create some sort of prototype of a C# application. My goal is to delete a file when it becomes available, so not locked by another process. Lots of times I need to read/delete/move files which are still in use cause they are being written by another application on the network. Network-delay causes the file-in-use exception.

For my demo I created another console application which writes every 5 sec. a line to the same file and in the mean time it keeps the file open, so this will work.

So I want to wrap the delete/move action in a Polly policy, but when I'll try there is still the `IOException`: file in use by another process. I assumed this was captured by Polly, but apparently I'm wrong...

What's wrong in this code ?
When I take a look at the `InnerException`, it's `null` ?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{     
    var MAX_RETRIES = 5;

    Console.WriteLine($"Attempting to delete the file {fileName}\r\nPress any key to continue....");
    Console.ReadKey();

    //Build the policy
    var retryPolicy = Policy
        .Handle<IOException>()
        .Or<Exception>()
        .Retry(MAX_RETRIES);

    //Execute the error prone code with the policy
    retryPolicy.Execute(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting File-deleting on {fileName}");
        if (File.Exists(fileName))
            File.Delete(fileName);      // <== here's where the exception occurs !

        Console.WriteLine("File deleted");
    });

    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit");
    
    var s = Console.ReadLine();
    if (s == "quit");
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: So what does the console output look like? Also, the "File deleted" output seems optimistic - it should at least be inside the `if`. And don't say "press any key" when you are looking for "quit" :) Especially when you are about to quit anyway.

Comment: The console output shows me two files: "Attempting to delete....." and "Starting File-deleting...". The exit etc, is just for myself and is absolutely production-ready code, not a change.

Comment: Perhaps you should use `WaitAndRetry` and set a pause between retries (unfortunately there isn't an overload for taking a single constant `TimeSpan` so you could use the lambda method option).

Comment: It's not captured unless you use ExecuteAndCapture. The way you are using it now it will retry MAX_RETRIES times and if it doesn't succeed it will rethrow the exception.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the both options works. In both cases it throws the exception at the first attempt. This is show by the message _"Starting File-deleting..."_ which is shown only once.  Seeing this behavior, it seems to be clear it isn't a timing/delay issue.

Comment: @kouwerp I've replaced your `File.Delete` with `throw new IOExecption` and the policy is triggered 5 times (so the output contained the `Starting File-deleting on ...` string six times). Are you sure that it throws `IOException`? If you look at the documentation [it can throw a lots of other exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.delete?view=net-6.0) as well.

Comment: @kouwerp I've created a separated app which opens the same file like this `File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None)` but your code was able to delete the file. So, could you please share with us how do lock the file from your other process?

Answer (score 0):

This is a little above my expertise as I have never used Polly, but one thing to try would be to throw a try catch inside of the `if(file.Exists(filename))`. Only bringing this up as it doesn't look like you are ever checking if it is in use after checking if it exists.

```
Console.WriteLine($"Starting File-deleting on {fileName}");
if (File.Exists(fileName))
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(fileName);
        Console.WriteLine("File deleted");
    } 
    catch
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("File in use..."); 
    }      
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed. The code I wrote works fine, but, so some reason, my IDE was set to break when this exception type is user-unhandled. I unchecked this it it's running file, just as it should